# How can i pass dynamic column name from one data frame to my conditions in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dynamic, delete-row

I have 3 data frames as follows:

```
df1 :
    Name   Data   Identifier
    Rojer  12e    e
    Punit  13q    q
df2:
    Name   Data   Identifier
    Rojer  12e    e

df3:
    ColumnName
    Name
    Identifier
```

I want to delete a row from df1 using some conditional column available as a data in df3

my code is as follows:

```
newdf <- df1[!(df1$Name == df2$Name && df1$Identifier == df2$Identifier)]
```

above code is working fine but i want to pass column name dynamically from df3 after $.

Please help!

Comment: Your original code returns an empty dataframe with 0 column and 2 rows. Just wanted to check if that's correct. If not, is this what you are trying to do instead? `newdf <- df1[!(df1$Name == df2$Name & df1$Identifier == df2$Identifier), ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you wanted to do?

```
library(dplyr)


df1 %>% 
  anti_join(df2, by = df3$ColumnName)

#    Name Data Identifier
# 1 Punit  13q          q
```

Comment: Thanks Zaw this is what i want to do but i want to pass Name, Identifier from df 3 , is there any way to do that ?

Comment: I updated the answer. I just plugged the strings using their index to the `anti_join()` call.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. What if i have more no of rows in df3 which i dont no like any way to add dynamicy

Comment: I think you can add `df3$ColumnName` directly assuming it has all the column names you wanted to `anti_join()`. Please see my updated answer.